# Ubuntu cannot detect operating system

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios

I have been having an issue with Ubuntu 17.04 hanging on the purple load screen and have only been able to fix the issue by changing to legacy/BIOS safe boot and selecting 'nomodeset'. Now when trying to install alongside Windows it says it cannot find the operating system, is this related to legacy boot mode? (Windows 10; AMD FX9800p; Radeon R7)

Comment: yes, legacy mode can not read a GPT disk. you should be able to boot the installer in EFI mode with `nomodeset`. and secure boot turned off

Comment: No, ravery, a legacy-mode boot of Ubuntu has no problems reading a GPT disk. The problem likely has other causes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues that may be causing you problems, or that might cause problems if you continue down your current path....

- **Boot mode** -- Since Windows 8, the vast majority of new computers have shipped configured to boot in EFI/UEFI mode. If your computer is so configured, installing Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode will create follow-on problems, since switching boot modes is awkward. I realize you say that this is the only way you've gotten the installer to boot, but you may want to spend more time on this point. If you really can't get the Ubuntu installer to boot in EFI mode, you'll need to use either the computer's own boot manager (which is awkward and, in some cases, literally insufficient) to switch OSes, or my own [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) (which is less awkward to use but harder to install; and even it doesn't always work).
- **Black screen problems** -- A wide range of issues can lead to "black screen" problems. See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076) for details. You might or might not have one of these problems, but that's where I'd suggest beginning your search for a solution. If you can't find a solution that enables booting in EFI mode, I recommend you post with more details, including your computer make and model. Linux generally, and Ubuntu specifically, work with most computers; but some models simply are not compatible, or require model-specific workarounds. Such problems are most common with very new hardware, for which drivers might not yet be available or might contain bugs.
- **Windows Fast Startup and Hibernate** -- Your description seems to suggest that the Ubuntu installer is not presenting the usual "install alongside" type options. This symptom is sometimes caused by use of the Windows Fast Startup and/or Hibernate features, which are enabled by default. It's *imperative* that these features be disabled in any dual-boot configuration. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for information on doing so. Disabling these features might or might not present you with easier installation options; I've seen reports both ways on that. If you don't disable these features, though, you run the risk of suffering filesystem damage in the future, and this damage can cause boot failures, lost personal data, or completely trashed installations.
- **"Something Else" installation** -- If disabling Fast Startup and Hibernate doesn't produce the "install alongside" installation options, you'll need to do manual partitioning with the "something else" option, as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) Note that, if you install in BIOS mode, you must create a ~1MiB [BIOS Boot Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) along with whatever other partitions you might want.

There's also a possibility that there's something very quirky about your computer or its configuration. If you continue to have problems, you can run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing mode" and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. Chances are this won't reveal anything odd, though. I suspect your symptoms are caused by a failure to disable Fast Startup and/or Hibernate, and/or by an idiosyncratic hardware problem that will require some system-specific workaround. The BootInfo summary won't help diagnose these problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to install Ubuntu in EFI mode however now I do not get the normal GNU GRUB with the option to select either Ubuntu or Windows, only the one which states "Minimal BASH-like line editing..." from which I am able to 'exit' to the standard windows boot menu. From there I can boot Windows 10 but trying to boot Ubuntu only takes me back to the same grub menu that does not show any boot options..

Comment: It sounds like you've got a damaged and/or duplicate GRUB installation. I suggest posting a new question. Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided to the new question. Alternatively, you could try installing my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which might bypass the problem.